# How to parse powershell style command line arguments in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, arguments

I have a string. Something like this:

```
myapp.exe email --to myemail@mail.com --subject "EmailSubject" --body "Test message".
```

How to parse every param value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either go the manual way and build your dictionary of key-values: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx

Or use a third party Nuget package, such as this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/commandlineparser, which will add support for more advanced and higher level scenarios

Comment: Command line parser is incredibly useful. It saves so much time over the manual method, and is incredibly easy to plug in and get working.

Comment: @fabilio-salvalai thank you. I have just installed this library. I'm viewing their wiki now.

Comment: @DavidWatts, tq. Do you have some samples that use this library? (uses verbs as "email")

Comment: @Nemesis nothing of my own right now, but there is an example on their codeplex page https://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks to all)) As @DavidWatts said it is very usefull and simple. I've viewed their docs and my problem is fully solved.